# Dart Language: printing reports

Tags: printing, dart, report, dart-html

I would like to know how to print reports on Dart.

**Basically, this is the activity flow:**

1. User clicks "Report" button.
2. New browser window is created.
3. Related data gets placed in the new window.

Of course that if there's any API to do that, I would use it.

So far, I've tried to create a new window, add onMessage listener on it and call postMessage on the main class to send data. However, it didn't work. The message never gets to the other side (main > new browser window).

**Main Dart Class**

```dart
var reportWindow;
void createReportWindow() {
    reportWindow = window.open("report.html", "");
}
void sendMessage(String message) {
    reportWindow.postMessage(message, "*");
}
```

**Report Dart Class** (linked to report.html)

```dart
void startListening() {
    window.onMessage.listen((e) {
        print(e.data.toString());
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Update

Start sending from the report window to `window.opener.postMessage(...)` and then respond to `(message.source as WindowBase).postMessage(...)`.
This is probably a bug with the return value of `window.open` (see http://dartbug.com/20216 for more details).

#### Original

The code in this unit test should show you how it can be done https://github.com/dart-lang/core-elements/blob/master/test/core_media_query_test.dart.

I open a window from a new URL that loads its content and a Dart script (can of course also be compiled to JavaScript) from the server. The opened window communicates with the main window by `sendMessage`. This works in both directions.

Basically the second window is a second Dart browser application.

This might not exactly be what you were looking for but your requirement could realized this way I guess.

At this line https://github.com/dart-lang/core-elements/blob/master/test/core_media_query_test.dart#L66 the commented out code would probably fit for your requirement. I created the workaround below because the code is supposed to resize the second window from code in the main window to test the `<core-media-query>` element (doesn't work either btw.). But I assume you just need to open the window and the commented out code should do exactly that just fine.

Comment: Your instructions worked fine. The only problem is about data length. I'm sending data through postMessage and it's being truncated. I think I'll have to do it other way.

Comment: You can also use the optional `transfer` argument, there shouldn't be a limit.